# TikZ adding captions to tree diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am adding several tree diagrams to my latex document, nad I want to add captions to the trees to explain what they are.

Is there an easy way to do this with tikZ, or do I have to use something else to add the caption?

Comment: Why not put the TikZ tree in a `figure` environment and just use `\caption{}`?

Comment: If you don't want to float, you can use \captionof from the caption package.  If you don't like the way caption looks, you can just write your own caption and put both it and the tikzpicture into a tabular.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It is hard to know what you are asking as it is - people are therefore reduced to guessing.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line at the very end of your `tikzpicture`.

```
\node[below]at(current bounding box.south){This figure shows something really special};
```

Answer (score 3):

I just tried, simply add like following

```
\begin{figure}

\centering #as you wish

#your TikZ tree code#

\caption{your title}

\end{figure}
```

by this way, you created this tree as a figure. Hope it helps.

Comment: To the down-voter: please don't down-vote posts without indicating how they can be improved, especially in the case of posts by users new to the site.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @cfr I guess this is because OP asked for Ti*k*Z solution. (But considering labeling, numbering, font, etc, using `figure` is way better.)